# Unwanted vertices in Vertex Groups

Tags: vertices, weight-painting, vertex-groups

So I've got this weird thing going on with vertex groups.

I rigged a character, parented it to the mesh.
Then when I started to weight paint I noticed there were vertices that where already assigned to the just created vertex group.
I thought "weird" but I selected them and clicked the Remove button of this vertex group and went on to paint the other parts of the body.

Then later I realized that when I click on a vertex group and on the Select button, if I'm on Weight Paint Mode, I have unwanted vertices that are selected all over the body. But this does not happen if I click on the Select button when in Edit Mode...
Again, if I remove the unwanted ones, it appears as if they are indeed removed when in Edit Mode, but if I go back to Weight Paint Mode and Select the vertex group again, they pop back up again...

Here's a picture of the character. The selected vertices pop up when I select my "Head" vertex group even after I just removed all of them:
[image: Unwanted Vertices on Head Vertex Group]

Any idea what's going on here? Is this a bug or something? Am I doing something wrong?